# How to change text in a value in an AJAX function?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

Is there a way to change data you receive when you GET data from an API? I'm new at using AJAX to get API data from TikTok and can get the embed code. The problem I'm having to how to change data once you've gotten it. I've used `.find()` and `.replaceWith()` and I get an error message saying `find is not a function` and `replacewith is not a function`.

The code that you get back from TikTok API for embedding a video on your site looks like this:

```
<blockquote class="tiktok-embed">
```

and I need to change the class to call it something else:

```
<blockquote class="tiktok-video">
```

My code so far:

```js
$('.btn').click(function() {
  
  $('.text').text('loading . . .');
  
  $.ajax({
    type:"GET",
    url:"https://www.tiktok.com/@fatcapsprays/video/7105385471500455174",
    success: function(data) {
      // Problem is here
      $('.text').text(JSON.stringify(data.html));
    },
    dataType: 'JSON',
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button type="button" class="btn">Click me!</button>
<p class="text">Code</p>
```

P.S. TikTok seems to be having problems accessing it's API as of this post for me.

Comment: "ajax" is basically a way to asynchronously receive data. If that result is json once "parsed" its a javascript object. So all normal ways to change its properties apply.

Comment: Many websites, including TikTok, implement a [CORS policy](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/CORS) which prevents other websites from making requests to them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can replace the class name in the string using `String.prototype.replace` method:
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace

Using your example:

```
  $.ajax({
    type:"GET",
    url:"https://www.tiktok.com/@fatcapsprays/video/7105385471500455174",
    success: function(data) {
      // Problem is here
      $('.text').text(JSON.stringify(data.html.replace('tiktok-embed', 'tiktok-video'));
    },
    dataType: 'JSON',
  });
});
```

p.s. - According to the TikTok documentation, you should be making your requests to `https://www.tiktok.com/oembed?url=UrlToYourVideo` not the direct video link
See: https://developers.tiktok.com/doc/embed-videos

Comment: Thank you so much! I've been looking all over for a solution and now I've found it.

Answer (score 0):

search on google with key "jquery api". you can find anything provided api by author to manipulate your DOM.

On your problem, i think you can use api addClass function to manipulate class of DOM

https://api.jquery.com/